# Calculating centripetal force if force is known instead velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, centripetal-force

How do I calculate centripetal force if applied force is known instead of velocity?

[image: Centripetal Force]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

we know  : $$F=ma$$

$\therefore \ a\ _{tangent} = dv\ _{tangent}/dt $

$ \int_0^v dv\ _{tangent} = \int_0^t dt \  a _{tangent}$ =

If F is constant , |a| is constant .

$v\ _{tangent} =a_t \ t$

$a_{c}= v^2_{tan}/r_{inst}$

Comment: F is constant, yes. What if velocity is not changing ? Which means acceleration is 0.

Comment: @Kitiara It becomes uniform circular motion.